Full screen and screen reader issue

I am  working on full-screen feature, it has a button & on click of which it expands to full screen,
but screen reader says "Exiting full screen" when pressing full-screen button, instead it should announce "Entering full screen".

Steps  to produce:

Go to codepen link on microsoft edge browser.


Here is Code Pen link <https://codepen.io/ashish_ga/pen/mybwymR


Start windows narrator by pressing  ctrl + window key+ enter key.

Go to go full screen button through tab key and hit enter.

observe narrator says "Exiting full screen".

Intsead, it should say "Entering full screen"



Could you tell us what you expect by setting top: -9999px;? Obviously, the div is not visible then, so even no "Exiting full screen" would be displayed. Maybe you can give us a screenshot to illustrate this problem? FYI, removing top: -9999px; successfully shows "Entering full screen mode" when I click the button.

Hi @KendrickLim, thanks for the response, I have updated the question with steps.
